# Alternative to sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/web

Tags: ppa, software-sources, add-apt-repository

I found [these steps](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/04/how-...b-service.html) to install SoapUI but I cannot connect because of a proxy.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
 "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 125, in <module>
     ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 80,
 in get_ppa_info_from_lp
     curl.perform() pycurl.error: (7, "couldn't connect to host")
```

I don't have problems with apt-get update, so is there any way to install SoapUI modifying sources.list?

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions on adding PPAs here: [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

(alternatively, use the method below)

---

Yes. The PPA page on Launchpad has the information needed in "Technical details about this PPA":

[image]

Select the version from the drop down and it will show you the exact lines to copy. For example, for 12.04 (`precise`), you can add the following two lines to your `sources.list` file, or a new `.list` file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/web/ubuntu precise main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/web/ubuntu precise main
```

You then need to run the following, using the key fingerprint:

```
gpg --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net --recv DED04C8CBB517AE45B073F12A5D712AEE06E6293
gpg --export --armor E06E6293 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Or use a web interface like http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/ to get the key manually, and then add it using `sudo apt-key add path/to/file`.

Then update your sources to use the new PPA:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: thanks, its working but I'm getting this error when i try to update: Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A5D712AEE06E6293 Im not getting this error when i remove those lines.

Comment: @tirengarfio I've updated it